# calling ant script file from Java class itself

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have a query that is - I have a separate xml file named `abc.xml` which is an xml file having ant tasks in it. Now i can execute that file from ant perspective through eclipse that is it different tasks i can execute but, now what i am planning is to execute that xml from the java class itself and from the main method inside that java class can i execute that `abc.xml` ? please advise, is it possible to call the ant script file that is in form of an xml file through itself

I was also going through [run ant manually](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

I have separate task named as init in the `abc.xml` file

what i have tries in side the main method of java class is

```
File buildFile = new File("abc.xml");
           Project p = new Project();
           p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
           p.init();
           ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
           p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
           helper.parse(p, buildFile);
           p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

but the error that i am getting is..

```
Exception in init: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Locator
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.fromURI(FileUtils.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Location.<init>(Location.java:87)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Location.<init>(Location.java:70)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$ProjectHandler.onStartElement(ProjectHelper2.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.startElement(ProjectHelper2.java:465)
```

Comment: Is this the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes it is the complete stack trace

Comment: Whats the version of ant.jar and ant-launcher jar?

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator` can be found in `ant-launcher.jar`. Check **CLASSPATH** of your porgram and make sure `ant-launcher.jar` and other required jars are available.